# How to add columns to an existing csv file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiple-columns

I have this code that reads through my csv files ( p01_results, p02_results, ..... ) to remove some unwanted rows based on its number from, and it works. Right now I trying to add two columns `participantID` and `session`. For `participantID` I tried to read the name of the csv file, save the ID number (01,02, ...) and fill the column with it. For `session`, I tried to fill every 18 rows with 1s, 2s, 3s and 4s.

I tried to use this code into mine, but didn't work:

```
test4 = ['test4', 4, 7, 10]

with open(data.csv, 'r') as ifile 
    with open(adjusted.csv, 'w') as ofile:
        for line, new in zip(ifile, test4):
            new_line = line.rstrip('\n') + ',' + str(new) + '\n'
            ofile.write(new_line)

import os



base_directory = 'C:\\Users\\yosal\\Desktop\\results'    
for dir_path, dir_name_list, file_name_list in os.walk(base_directory):
    for file_name in file_name_list:
        # If this is not a CSV file
        if not file_name.endswith('results.csv'):
            # Skip it
            continue
        file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, file_name)
        with open(file_path, 'r') as ifile:
            line_list = ifile.readlines()
        with open(file_path, 'w') as ofile:
            # only write these rows to the new file
            ofile.writelines(line_list[0])
            ofile.writelines(line_list[2:20])
            ofile.writelines(line_list[21:39])
            ofile.writelines(line_list[40:58])
            ofile.writelines(line_list[59:77])
```

Comment: the first part of your code seems like a legit try, whats your exact problem, error, stacktrace, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the CSV into a list. Then, loop through each element of the list (each element being a row in the CSV), and add a string with the delimieter plus the desired string. Then, write a new CSV, either named differently or replacing the old one, and just use your list as the input.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding a column to my csv file using pandas. So you can try out something like this. First you have to install pandas by running "pip install pandas".

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')  ## read  the csv file
df.set_index('S/N', inplace=True) ## you can set an index with any column 
                                  ##you have that already exists in your csv 
                                  ##in my case it is the "S/N" column i used 
df["test"] = ["values","you want","add"]
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Took me some time, but I did it.

```py
import os



base_directory = 'C:\\Users\\yosal\\Desktop\\results'    
for dir_path, dir_name_list, file_name_list in os.walk(base_directory):
    for file_name in file_name_list:
        # If this is not a CSV file
        if not file_name.endswith('results.csv'):
            # Skip it
            continue
        file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, file_name)
        with open(file_path, 'r') as ifile:
            line_list = ifile.readlines()
        with open(file_path, 'w') as ofile:
            ofile.writelines(str(line_list[0]).rstrip()+",participant,session\n")
            for x in range(2, 20):
                 ofile.writelines(str(line_list[x]).rstrip()+","+file_path[len(base_directory)+2:len(base_directory)+4]+",1\n")
            for y in range(21, 39):
                 ofile.writelines(str(line_list[y]).rstrip()+","+file_path[len(base_directory)+2:len(base_directory)+4]+",2\n")
            for h in range(40, 58):
                ofile.writelines(str(line_list[h]).rstrip()+","+file_path[len(base_directory)+2:len(base_directory)+4]+",3\n")
            for z in range(59 ,77):
                ofile.writelines(str(line_list[z]).rstrip()+","+file_path[len(base_directory)+2:len(base_directory)+4]+",4\n")
```